# Convert a 24hr number to time in a WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to take a 4-digit number (e.g. 0900) and convert it into a time. I took the route of just formatting the number and adding the colon, which worked fine until I realized that needed to be output in 12hr with the am/pm. I'm wrapping the function in a WordPress shortcode to use it for a custom field output.

```
function hel_format_time($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    $time = substr_replace($content, ':', 2, 0);
    return $time;
}
add_shortcode('format-time', 'hel_format_time');
```

This will translate the content of 0900 into 09:00 but what I need is 0900 into 9:00 am.

Comment: How do you determine am or pm?

Comment: The 24-hour time would be 2100 if it was 9 pm.

Comment: So you also need to subtract 12 from the hours or it should be 21:00?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert army time into am/pm format. If that is the case, please! try this.

```
function hel_format_time($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    $time = date("h:i a", strtotime($content));
    return $time;
}
add_shortcode('format-time', 'hel_format_time');
```

Thanks

Comment: So when I test this I get the result from "0900" which gets converted into "09:00" which is mostly there but missing the am/pm. Is this converting from 24hr to 12hr?